# Padding around container of section

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why I am having such a hard time with this small issue, but I cannot get a container's padding set like I want it. I want there to be a percentage padding, based on the main container `#contact-section` to be applied to `#contact-section-wrap`. Everything I try will not work. I have attempted to make it margin, applying `position:relative;` to `#contact-section`, but everything I do doesn't work.

[image]

[Here is a jsfiddle as well.](https://jsfiddle.net/cs3wtwor/)

```css
#contact-section {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
}
#contact-section-left,
#contact-section-right {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#contact-section-left {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#contact-section-right {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-wrap">
    <div id="contact-section-left">
      Tell us more about your project.
    </div>
    <div id="contact-section-right">
      Contact us
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Move your "padding: 5%;" from #contact-section-wrap to #contact-section

Comment: @Armin I have done this, but then it takes the section out of viewport on the right side.

Comment: Add box-sizing: border-box to #contact-section

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cs3wtwor/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the fixed `height: 150px;` on `#contact-section`, also remove the `width`, `height` on a couple of the inner elements, it should be OK.

```css
#contact-section {
  /* height: 150px; */
  width: 100%;
  background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section-wrap {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  padding: 5%;
}
#contact-section-left,
#contact-section-right {
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#contact-section-left {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#contact-section-right {
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-wrap">
    <div id="contact-section-left">
      Tell us more about your project.
    </div>
    <div id="contact-section-right">
      Contact us
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add box-sizing to all `#contact-section` child elements with this code:

```
#contact-section * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: What will this do?

Comment: It will change te way that margin and paddings are calculated.

Answer (score 1):

How about flex-box? It will be very easy, like this:

```
#contact-section {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00a16d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#contact-section-wrap {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `#contact-section` contains padding, instead of its parent element `#contact-section-wrap`.

Move your `padding: 5%;` from `#contact-section-wrap` to `#contact-section`, and add `box-sizing: border-box` to `#contact-section`.

Box-sizing basically decides if padding and border should be included in the element's total width and height. In your case you want them included so your `padding: 5%` is included in `width:100%` (otherwise you would have total width: 110%)

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cs3wtwor/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your current approach, you need `box-sizing: border-box;`.

By default, if you set `width: 100%` and `padding: 5%`, the actual width of the element is calculated to be 110% (padding on the left & right = 10%).

If you use `box-sizing: border-box;`, the actual element width matches the `width` value. (The same applies to `height`)

```css
#contact-section {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section-wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
}
#contact-section-left, #contact-section-right {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#contact-section-left {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#contact-section-right {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-wrap">
    <div id="contact-section-left">
      Tell us more about your project.
    </div>
    <div id="contact-section-right">
      Contact us
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```